# Updating a Maybe Record in Elm

Tags: elm

I have an app where a user can create projects. The `currentProject` in the model is a `Maybe Project` type with the initial value set to `Nothing` (since there may be no projects created yet by that user).

```
type alias Project =
    { name : String }

type alias Model =
    { user : User
    , currentProject : Maybe Project
    }
```

This is in the `init` for the Model:

`currentProject = Nothing`

I then have a dropdown where the user can select a project. Upon selecting it the `onClick` calls the following update:

```
type Msg
    = ...
    | SetProject Project
```

The update function that I try to run looks like this:

```
SetProject project ->
    case project of
       Just project ->
         ( { model | currentProject = project }, Cmd.none )

       Nothing ->
         ( model, Cmd.none )
```

I get an error because `project` is of type `Project` and not `Maybe Project`.

I know the project exists because it's coming from an existing list of projects in the app. But, I cannot set `currentProject` to type `Project` because I need to initialize the Model with `Nothing`.

So, how can I update the `Maybe Project` record with type `Project`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`Just`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Maybe#Maybe) constructor:

```
SetProject project ->
     ( { model | currentProject = Just project }, Cmd.none )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I still receive a compiler error saying that `Just project` pattern matches the type `Maybe a` but the value it's trying to match is `Project`. Do you mean in lieu of the case expression?

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the case expression and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, I just updated my answer to reflect that. The reason is because `SetProject` is not defined in terms of `Maybe`

Answer (score 4):

Your message says you are expecting a Project type, but then you are pattern matching on it to check to see if it is a (Maybe Project) but it isn't. So, either pass in a Maybe Project in your msg or change your update function to be this.

```
SetProject project ->
    ( { model | currentProject = Just project }, Cmd.none )
```